# Having Issues with Segmentation Error in Doubly Linked List Implementation

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I'm pretty new to C and I can't figure out why I'm getting a segmentation fault from this code:

```
void delete_list(LIST *list)
{
  NODE* n = list->head;
  while(n != list->tail)
  {
    NODE* next = n->next;
    free(n);
    n = next;
  }
  free(n);
  free(list);
}
```

I'm pretty certain this is the part of my code that's has the error, but if not I can post the rest of my code. Both NODE and LIST are created using malloc(). The code is the barebones framework for a doubly-linked-list.

EDIT 2: Here's the code to reproduce what I'm doing. Very basic test case but it is failing. First is the header file list.h, then the main file list.c. I also eradicated the first edit to clean up the question a bit.

```
#ifndef __LIST_H__
#define __LIST_H__

typedef struct node {
  char *value;  /* Pointer to the string we are storing. */
  struct node *previous;  /* Pointer to the preceding node in the list. */
  struct node *next;  /* Pointer to the next node in the list. */
} NODE;

typedef struct list {
  NODE *head;  /* Pointer to the first node in the list. */
  NODE *tail;  /* Pointer to the last node in the list. */
} LIST;

/* Function prototypes the public interface. */
LIST *new_list(const char *value);
void prepend(LIST *list, const char *value);
void append(LIST *list, const char *value);
void delete_list(LIST *list);

#endif
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "list.h"

NODE *new_node(const char *value);

LIST *new_list(const char *value)
{
  LIST *list = (LIST*) malloc(sizeof(LIST));
  NODE* n = new_node(value);
  list->head = n;
  list->tail = n;

  return list;
}

void prepend(LIST *list, const char *value)
{
  NODE* n = new_node(value);
  n->next = list->head;
  list->head->previous = n;
  list->head = n;
}

void append(LIST *list, const char *value)
{
  NODE* n = new_node(value);
  n->previous = list->tail;
  list->tail->next = n;
  list->tail = n;
}

void delete_list(LIST *list)
{
  NODE* n = list->head;
  while(n != list->tail)
  {
    NODE* next = n->next;
    free(n);
    n = next;
  }
  free(n);
  free(list);
}

NODE *new_node(const char *value)
{
  NODE *node = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));

  node->value = (char*) malloc((strlen(value) + 1) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(node->value, value);
  node->previous = NULL;
  node->next = NULL;
  
  return node;
}

void print_list(const LIST *list)
{
  /* Print the contents of a list. */
  for (NODE *node = list->head; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
    printf("%s\n", node->value);
  }
}

int main()
{
  char *middle = "middle";
  char *last = "last";
  char *first = "first";
  LIST* list = new_list(middle);
  prepend(list, first);
  append(list, last);
  print_list(list);
  delete_list(list);
  print_list(list);
}
```

Comment: Use a *debugger* to catch the crash "in action", to locate when and where in your code it happens and to examine the values of all involved variables at the time and location of the crash.

Comment: *"'i'm pretty certain this is the part of my code that's has the error,"* -- nope. You may find [Doubly-Linked List of Integers - Remove Rand Nodes Check](https://pastebin.com/E6WpPjTC) useful.

Comment: Yes, you should [edit] and post a [mcve]. The problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on __reproducible__). Lots of things are missing for example what is `LIST`, what is `new_node`, where is `main`, etc.? How do you call all these functions and with what data?

Comment: I've always found it easier to create the list with the node pointers `NULL` and only allocate for the node when you add (`append` or `prepend`) a node to the list. Avoids the quirky (Is the node allocated? -- issue...) You want to eliminate special cases (e.g. first, last) if you can.

Comment: After `delete_list(list)`, `list` points to freed memory, therefore it's pretty normal that `print_list` doesn't work as expected. It's just like `...; free(p); DoSomething(p);`. The rest of your code seems correct to me.

Comment: Yeah that is the implementation I usually go for but since I am being guaranteed every new list will have a node and I cannot remove nodes from a list, I am just setting the head and tail of the list to the starting node. I might be misunderstanding what you're saying though, David.

Comment: Oh my gosh my error was in the test code! Thanks for your patience and help, Jabberwocky. I'll let you all know after I fix my testing code if everything works as expected.

Comment: @JacobPod I recommend you learn how to user your debugger. With a debugger (even with most basic usage) this kind of errors can be found in minutes.

Comment: It all looks good to me, but if anyone spots any possible memory leaks please don't hesitate to comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can't

```c
  delete_list(list);
  print_list(list);
```

The list is gone after delete. (you invoke *Undefined Behavior* at that point) The only other issue you have is you fail to `free()` `node->value`.

You can fix that with:

```c
void delete_list(LIST *list)
{
  NODE* n = list->head;
  while(n != list->tail)
  {
    NODE* next = n->next;
    free(n->value);
    free(n);
    n = next;
  }
  free (n->value);
  free(n);
  free(list);
}
```

Your code works fine then.

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/list
==9065== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9065== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9065== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9065== Command: ./bin/list
==9065==
first
middle
last
==9065==
==9065== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9065==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9065==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 1,130 bytes allocated
==9065==
==9065== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9065==
==9065== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9065== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Alternative Delete List**

You may find the following alternative for `delete_list()` a bit more readable -- up to you:

```c
void delete_list (LIST *list)
{
  NODE *n = list->head;
  
  while (n) {
    NODE *victim = n;
    n = n->next;
    free (victim->value);
    free (victim);
  }
  free (list);
}
```